# Databse connection pool thread starvation

Tags: java, database, multithreading, hikaricp

I am working on an application that requires me to flush data in the database every 24h. We could have millions of data to flush. Code-wise, everything is threaded on my side. The observation goes as following, I was able to flush half a million records in no time. Then I went to try to flush 5 million records. The server application doe not crash but I get this warning:

WARN 2076 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=51s629ms256µs700ns).

Eventually, it ends up with exceptions like server connection broken.... The server in question is the database server.

```
2021-03-10 13:35:38,420 ERROR [Thread-802] c.n.j.j.p.ProjectDAO [ProjectDAO.java:1145] Some error has occurred with your query.
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 33285ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:689)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:196)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:161)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
    at com.nomadlogic.juju.jdbc.projectDAO.ProjectDAO.getRespondentsReadyForPostSync(ProjectDAO.java:1119)
    at com.nomadlogic.juju.jdbc.projectDAO.ProjectDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$85fa6901.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.nomadlogic.juju.jdbc.projectDAO.ProjectDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f453eb9.getRespondentsReadyForPostSync(<generated>)
    at com.nomadlogic.juju.post_synchronization.PostSynchronizationThread.run(PostSynchronizationThread.java:84)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: Your DB server can't handle the load? A classic case of "how do I efficiently batch a lot of data"?

Answer (score 2):

You don't give us any details, but here's what I would probably do:  write the "flush" so that it only tries to do – say – half-a-million rows at a time.  Then, repeat that process as often as necessary until you are told that there are no more records to flush. *One* "flusher process" gets the job done, using a loop.  Be very sure that the process does not try to run in parallel ...

(By the way: "Thread starvation" rather-strongly suggests that maybe that's what it's trying to do. Otherwise, why on earth would a pool of threads become "starved?"  Well, if all of them were [incorrectly ...] trying to do a time-consuming task *simultaneously ...)*

Comment: Thanks, I have made a little walk around by processing by little chunks